# Is there working IE11 HTML Date Picker? (No JS and or Bootstrap)

Tags: html

i would like to ask if anyone can help me with my **Date Picker** problem. I need a **Date Picker** that will work on **IE11** but does not include JS and Bootstrap. The thing is, the company i am working does not allow other browsers (Chrome, Firefox etc.), only IE, also does not allow Scripting (use of JS).

thanks in advance :)

Comment: With no JS, all you can use is the built-in `<input type="date">`. So there's nothing to recommend. Recommendation requests are off-topic anyway.

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: This article describes various implementations of a date picker across multiple browsers in HTML5:

https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073678/html5-date-picker.html

Comment: I am using <input type="date"></input> but it appear as text only on internet explorer 11 :(

Answer (score 1):

This tag isn't supported in IE11. Here is the example of a select code.

```
<form action="link">
<select name="select1">
<option>Select Date</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
<select name="select2">
<option>Select Date</option>
<option>Jan</option>
<option>Feb</option>
</select>
<select name="select3">
<option>Select Date</option>
<option>2017</option>
<option>2018</option>
</select>
</form>
```

This can work. But the problem is that you aren't using javascript. The user can enter dates like 30 Feb which never occurs.

Comment: thanks sir Keshav, i have already tried that but its not working on IE11, but it works on Chrome, which stresses me because the company im working doesnt allow other browser except IE11

Comment: @ThollitezTurqueza: Then you're completely stuck.  Tell the company to drop that insane policy.

Comment: thanks to everyone who answer my question :) i've already tried deep searching on google but i've got nothing that work solely for IE, i will just use number type then make a validation. i appreciated all your inputs.. thank you.

Comment: You can use the select options.